# get content of iframe from another domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, iframe

I have an iframe from another domain. Since It's not possible to edit anything I want to read the content of the iframe.

The iframe has 4 pages. On the fourth page there is some text(example:"It's done"). I want to write something to a MySql database if the text appears in the iframe.

To accomplish this I need two things. 1. Read the contents of the iframe. 2. Execute this code part every X milliseconds to find the text I'm searching for.

```
1:  var iframe = document.querySelector('#id_description_iframe');
    var iframeContent;

    if (iframeDocument) {
        iframeContent = iframeDocument.querySelectorAll('#frameBody');
    }

2:    window.setInterval(function_name, 10000);
```

I was wondering if this doesn't conflict with the same origin policy?

Second thing I was wondering about: How do I then write this to mysql database?

1: Make another page that receives a value throught GET method.

2: By the JS on the iframe page call another tab if the text has been found. The url would be the get url.

3: There save it to the mysql database.

4: after page loaded close tab again.

Really hope someone can help me out. Excuse me if the question isn't clear since I did really try to make it a really clear question.

Comment: If the `X-Frame` option is set to `Deny` then you won't be able to frame it even it's from same origin. More about [X-Frame and Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: I'm 100% able to iframe it. It is to sell tickets on your own website. I need to know if they completed the sale.

Comment: Of course this will conflict with the Same Origin Policy – since the iframe content is from another domain, you have no access to its content via JS from your main page. // _“It is to sell tickets on your own website. I need to know if they completed the sale.”_ – and the system you are using provides no other means of being notified of that?

Comment: No they can't. They can put a pixel in to see conversion but then I only know a sale has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Get all content of other site:

```
 var pageContent, iframe, iframeContent, iframeUrl = null;
 pageContent.load(<url>);
 iframeContent = pageContent.find('iframe')[0];
 iframeUrl = iframeContent.attr('src');
 iframe = pageContent.load(iframeUrl);
```

Then, the content of iFrame is read to use on 'iframe' variable.